# How to invoke an AWS Step Function using an GET API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

How do I invoke an AWS Step Function using an API Gateway **GET** request, and the request's JSON payload to the Step Function?

I need the API Gateway to start a Step Function which then invokes a Lambda function that uses the URL input parameter **'pk'**.

I have tried this by adding a mapping template within the integration request section.
It looks like this:

```
{
    "input": {
        "pk": "$input.params('pk')"
    }
    "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-central-1:............"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out [Serverlessland](https://serverlessland.com/) and specifically the [Workflows Collection](https://serverlessland.com/workflows). Lots of awesome examples! You can filter by service to show [examples that involve API Gateway](https://serverlessland.com/workflows?services=apigw). Here's [a specific example that might be helpful for you](https://serverlessland.com/workflows/synchronous-api).

There's also a module in the [Step Functions Workshop](https://catalog.workshops.aws/stepfunctions/en-US/module-7) that covers this topic.

Hope this helps!